Conky doesn't show wifi traffic
My conky show cpu, memory, harddisk but doesn't show wifi traffic of my lapttop. I ran:
ifconfig
...
wlp4s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.71.85  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.71.255
        inet6 fe80::1444:7aea:732f:e5e9  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 36:ce:4f:4d:48:6d  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 35804  bytes 37186607 (35.4 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 28512  bytes 8665499 (8.2 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

so I use wlp4s0 in conky settings:
# Network data
${voffset 43}
${offset 90}${font Ubuntu:size=10,weight:bold}${color5}WiFi
${voffset 40}             
${offset 15}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Up: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}$color2${upspeed wlp4s0} / ${totalup}
${offset 15}${upspeedgraph wlp4s0 40,285 4B1B0C FF5C2B 100 -l}
${offset 15}${color1}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:bold}Down: ${alignr}${font Ubuntu:size=9,weight:normal}$color2${downspeed wlp4s0} / ${totaldown}
${offset 15}${downspeedgraph wlp4s0 40,285 324D23 77B753 100 -l}

${color4}${hr 2}

but it doesn't work.
